# What is the nmake equivalent of filter-out?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make, nmake

I've been given a makefile for ubuntu, and I'm trying to use it with nmake on Windows 10.

nmake doesn't seem to recognize the `filter-out` keyword such as in the following line:

```
OBJS_TEST = $(filter-out $(EXE_OBJ), $(OBJS))
```

Does nmake have a keyword with the same functionality?

For completeness, the lines from the beginning of the file before the above line (and a few lines below) are as follows:

```
EXE = main
TEST = test
OBJS_DIR = .objs

###############################################
### THE LINE IN QUESTION IS BELOW #############
OBJS_TEST = $(filter-out $(EXE_OBJ), $(OBJS))
###############################################

CPP_TEST = $(wildcard tests/*.cpp)

# CPP_TEST += uiuc/catch/catchmain.cpp
# The above line doesn't work with the "+=" extension in nmake; replace with below.
CPP_TEST = $(CPP_TEST) $(wildcard tests/*.cpp)
```

The error reported is:

```
fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '-' in macro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no equivalent to `filter-out` in nmake.  Also, nmake does not support the `wildcard` function so you'll have to deal with that.  And, I'm suspicious that your replacement for `+=` won't work; in most versions of POSIX make `FOO = $(FOO)` is illegal as it gives an infinite loop of variable lookup.  Maybe nmake works differently, though.

nmake is *SO* different from POSIX make and GNU make that you will either have to rewrite the makefile from scratch, or else just go get a version of GNU make for Windows (or build it yourself).  GNU make is quite portable and runs well on Windows.  That would be a LOT less work.

Comment: wow, OK that's pretty emphatic. Thanks for saving me hours of time! ... I'm a bit puzzled about nmake now, though. I assumed it was for compatibility to POSIX and gnu make, but now it seems like a Microsoft-specific thing, and why would they bother with creating nmake when they already had vcxproj and sln files? (No need to answer, just thinking aloud).

Comment: I'm one of the last people who should be commenting on Windows tools, but nmake long predates visual studio, and its proj and sln files.